# Flutter Custom paint cross with path but with gradient and rounded corners

Tags: flutter, dart, custom-painting

I've just started getting to grips with Custom painter and I've created a basic cross but not sure how to make the corners rounded and make the colour a gradient?

It seems a gradient requires `createShader` which takes a `rect` but I don't have one since I used paths.

Also I'd like to round the corners of the cross a little but not sure how that is done. I thought about creating rectangles but it doesn't seem to be possible to create slanted rectangles either.

```
class CrossPainter extends CustomPainter {
  CrossPainter({this.bodyColour, this.strokeColour, this.stroke});
  final Color bodyColour;
  final Color strokeColour;
  final double stroke;
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint();
    paint
      ..color = strokeColour
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeWidth = stroke;

    Paint paint1 = Paint();
    paint1
      ..color = bodyColour
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..strokeWidth = 0;

    double width = size.width;
    double height = size.height;

    Path path = Path();
    path.addPolygon([Offset.zero, Offset(width / 4, 0), Offset(width, height), Offset(width - (width / 4), height)], true);
    Path path2 = Path();
    path2.addPolygon(
        [Offset(width, 0), Offset(width - (width / 4), 0), Offset(0, height), Offset(0 + (width / 4), height)], true);

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint1);
    canvas.drawPath(path2, paint1);
    // canvas.drawPath(path, paint); //border
    // canvas.drawPath(path2, paint); //border
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

I also have `paint1` which adds a border but it doesn't look so good since each polygon is a separate object.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199105/discussion-on-question-by-hasen-flutter-custom-paint-cross-with-path-but-with-gr).

Comment: @pskink Looking at this https://medium.com/flutteropen/canvas-tutorial-02-how-to-draw-round-angle-polygon-in-the-flutter-7890e933cfb1 it doesn't look like I can just make a polygon have rounded corners, it seems there's nothing built into flutter for that. I'd have to manually draw a polygon point to point and round each corner.

Comment: @Bhargav Rao♦  I don't think anyone ever gets any notification about chat. Once it moves to chat the other person tends to disappear.

Comment: For gradient, you can use shader property of path and create shader from gradient. `final paint = Paint()..shader = gradient.createShader(bounds);`

Answer (score 0):

You can freely use Rect on the Shader to fill gradient on rounded polygon drawn on the canvas. On my approach, I used the size defined on the canvas as a base for the Rect.

```dart
Paint()
  ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
  ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
  ..shader = gradient
      .createShader(Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height))
  ..strokeWidth = 20,
```

You can then add this paint object to the canvas that you're rendering.

As for the gradient, you can define it however you like. But here's an example.

```dart
const Gradient gradient = SweepGradient(
  startAngle: 1.25 * math.pi / 2,
  endAngle: 5.5 * math.pi / 2,
  tileMode: TileMode.repeated,
  colors: <Color>[
    Colors.blueAccent,
    Colors.lightBlueAccent,
  ],
);
```